# Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded, creating nomuerous html pages in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm creating 192 html pages using this function in the web.php file, but when it creates the fifth page gives me the error.

```php
function()
{
    $homepage = Page::find(1);
        
    $articles_show = Article::where(function ($query) {
        $query->where(function ($query2) {
            $query2->where('draft', 0)->whereNull('publication_date');
        })->orWhere(function ($query2) {
            $query2->where('draft', 0)->where('publication_date', '<=', DateHelper::currentDateTime());
        });
    })->orderBy('publicated_at', 'DESC')->get();

    $last_page = ceil($articles_show->count() / 8);
    $articles = [];
    $count = 0;

    for ($i = 5; $i <= $last_page; $i++) {
        $filename = 'page'.$i.'.html';
        
        $max_desc_id = $i * 8;
        $min_desc_id = $max_desc_id - 7;

        foreach ($articles_show as $article) {
            $count++;
            if ($article->desc_id >= $min_desc_id && $article->desc_id <= $max_desc_id) {
                $articles[] = $article;
            }
            if (($count % 8) == 0) {
                $count = 0;
            
                File::put(
                    resource_path('views/allArticlesHtml/'.$filename),
                    view('allArticlesTemplate')->with([
                        "articles" => $articles,
                        "homepage" => $homepage,
                        "this_page" => $i,
                        "last_page" => $last_page
                    ])->render()
                );
            
                continue;
            }
        }
        $articles = [];

        // if(($count % 8) == 0){
            
        // }
    }
}
```

The pages are created correctly but it's way too slow.
I don't really know if i am doing this in the right way or not, i'm still very new at programming and i don't know how to improve or recreate this code.

Comment: You probably created multiple questions about this. Here it is ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74849474/how-to-create-numuerous-pages-in-laravel-at-once-from-mysql-ids anyone is going to wonder WHY you want to create that many pages. You should ask yourself that question as well

Comment: @UnderDog My boss want’s this I don’t want to do it like this, and I’m struggling to do it because the things that he asks me are nonesense

Comment: I had this issue the other day. You can do this workaround:

Every time you create 1 file under that command put this:
`set_time_limit(30);`

Comment: @Tammapao can you accept my answer if it worked for you? Someone might need it later.

Comment: @devsead i can’t accept I comment, I’m sorry

Comment: Not posted yet, but even then it is not a problem if you don't :) Will leave it there

Comment: i've finally found out what was my problem with creating the files, with this code i was creating the same page multiple times, so i've added a switch that breaks the foreach loop and continues with the next page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue the other day. You can do this workaround:

Every time you create 1 file under that command put this:

```
set_time_limit(30);
```

It will reset the time limit to 30 seconds and every time reset it.

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 0):

I read your code. I'll try to suggest you best solution.

why you are trying to create html files with same content?
you can easily use blade engine and extend a template in different file.
to solve the error `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`
you need to increase `max_execution_time` value in `php.ini` file.
or put `ini_set('max_execution_time', 180)` at the top of php file .

but if you want an alternative way of creating files describe your initial problem.

Comment: Always because my boss is nonesense and he wants to have an html file for every view that a paginate file would do anyway

Comment: I understand :( . did you increase max_execution_time ?

Comment: I have finished to work for today I will do it tomorrow, but he even asked for a faster code to do the same thing

Comment: but 192 html files is too many. it has really bad effect on server and hosting. I think you are using wrong way

Comment: I know that creating that many files is a dumb idea but He asked for a .html file for every view and the files won’t even be 192 but more, because the site will have more articles…(the site is: sprechi.it) I even asked him to change idea but he didn’t

Comment: If he asked for .html files, we can work that out. 1) figure out if you're using an nginx server or apache, do that by running phpinfo() in a file on the server. 2) Try to find our how you can do url_rewritd for that specific server.

Comment: Now, the boss is the boss, so just make those files for him. What you can do is put it in a queue, which is a fancy way of hiding how long it takes. Then give him 2 answers: 1) the writing of the files is the bottleneck, you already increased the time-out. 2) you can rewrite the url to an .html file. Let's say that an article is /hello-world, you can either rewrite that with url-rewriting or by using a laravel route. You can let a route end in .html, no-one will ever know that you didn't write those 192 files